# Generate bit pattern

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to create a macro that generates a bit pattern as such:

`genmask(1)` gives `0xff00ff00..`

`genmask(2)` gives `0xffff0000..`

EDIT: `genmask(3)` gives `0xffffffff00000000`

so far I have `#define genmask(x) ((size_t)-1 / ((1 << 16 * (x)) - 1) * ((1 << 8 * (x)) - 1))`

which will not work due to lhs > type width, EDIT: and because `genmask(3)` has to give `0xffffffff00000000`

Comment: What should it give for `genmask(3)`?

Comment: Can't you just keep it simple and readable by defining an array?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Good catch, it would have to be 0xffffffff00000000 as 3 bytes of 1's and three of 0's wouldn't work

Comment: @WeatherVane You would still have to generate the patterns depending on if the size of size_t

Comment: @nwmcsween: yes, but could just as well use the patterns you want as hex literals, just as in the question above.

Comment: Note that the patterns are related [use *unsigned* type for mask values]: genmask(2)=(genmask(3)>>16)^genmask(3); genmask(1)=(genmask(2)>>8)^genmask(2)

Comment: @MOehm I don't think I could, as genmask(x) is generated by a function that specifies type width e.g `foo(void *s, size_t w, size_t n) { size_t mask = w <= sizeof(size_t) / 2 ? genmask(w) : -1 }` but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Isn't it easier to just define a table/switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define genmask(x) ((unsigned long long)-1 / ((1LL << (1LL << (x)) * 4) + 1) << (4 * (1 << (x))))
```

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/Z5qbQS)

There are only 4 values which are going to work 0-3. It is possible to write a separate macro for each of them.